# Capybara returns right URL but ghost page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

Here is what I have:

```
visit "..."

fill_in "Email", with: user.email
fill_in "Password", with: user.password
click_button "Sign in"

p current_url
p page.body    
save_and_open_page

fill_in "Email", with: "lol@lol.com"
click_button "Update"
```

current_url is correct

But page.body gives an empty page with only DOCTYPE, and it's an old HTML4 DOCTYPE that does not exist anywhere in the app!

save_and_open_page also gives empty page.

Any clues?

Comment: try add `visit current_url` above `p page.body`

Comment: try using p page.html instead. Is that something that involves Javascript at all? If you turn off JS in your browser, does that still work?

Comment: @jipiboily Nope, there are no JavaScript involved what-so-ever.

Comment: @Kien Thanh great idea! I should definitely try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this will be on-hold....the architecture changed and this is no longer needed...thanks for the help though...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what visit "..." Does but, when trying to visualize where the test is I like to add as an argument to the test method :js => true and then sleep 10 or however long wherever u want to pause execution, :js => true will load selenium and you can watch the tests being physically run and inspect the page if u sleep it.

Comment: Hmmm sounds like a great idea. Too bad I don't have time to learn Selenium until this project is over though..

Comment: The tests run exactly the same it just changes the driver from rack_test, to selenium, you don't need to do anything differently..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try visiting a specific page rather than using `"..."`?  So try `visit '/'`

Also, is capybara's `visit` working for you in other tests? It's possibly not loaded/working properly in general.

Comment: "..." is not the actual code, I took out the url because it's a distraction. And yes, visit "http://www.google.com" works perfectly, so does visit "/login" on this app.

Comment: Ah, well "..." does work as a visit command, so was just wondering. Anyway, very strange problem. It may be helpful to see the server log while the tests are running. Is capybara successfully getting the page? It may show a useful error.

Comment: Ahhhh...didn't know "..." is actually a valid visit argument. My bad. I'll def check the test log though.